# How to call two functions on "onClick" event?

Tags: javascript, onclick, submit

I have a "Spin" button. When clicked, I need this button to start spinning the wheel, but also to submit a form. The user can only start spinning the wheel once one of the radio buttons is selected.

Now, my onClick looks like this:

```js
onClick="startSpin()
```

and my startSpin() function looks like this:

```js
function startSpin()
{
    // Ensure that spinning can't be clicked again while already running.
    var lottery1 = document.getElementById("lottery1");
    var lottery2 = document.getElementById("lottery2");
    if (lottery1.checked==true || lottery2.checked==true) {
        if (wheelSpinning == false)
        {
            // Based on the power level selected adjust the number of spins for the wheel, the more times is has
            // to rotate with the duration of the animation the quicker the wheel spins.
            if (wheelPower == 1)
            {
                theWheel.animation.spins = 3;
            }
            else if (wheelPower == 2)
            {
                theWheel.animation.spins = 8;
            }
        }

        // Disable the spin button so can't click again while wheel is spinning.
        document.getElementById('spin_button').src       = "spin_off.png";
        document.getElementById('spin_button').className = "";

        // Begin the spin animation by calling startAnimation on the wheel object.
        theWheel.startAnimation();

        // Set to true so that power can't be changed and spin button re-enabled during
        // the current animation. The user will have to reset before spinning again.
        wheelSpinning = true;
    }
    document.getElementById('thisForm').submit();
}
```

The wheel spins perfectly without that very last line of code, but I need a submit button because I need to save the user data to a database. When I add that last line of code it interrupts the spin and I don't get to see the whole code being excecuted (after it stops to a segment of the wheel, I get an alert box telling me how much I won, based on which radio button I chose).

Comment: Spinning is stopped short because you're submitting a form. When a browser submits a form, it loads the server response as a new page. If you want to send data to the server and stay on the same page, you need AJAX for sending data.

Comment: Try using setTimeout:  `setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('thisForm').submit(); }, 500);`. This should allow the spinner to start.

Comment: @Mike67 I tried your code and it worked. I only needed to make the time longer. Thank you very much!